# A lottery that you can be convinced that it is fair

Tags: cr.crypto-security

(Sorry if this is well known.) I would like to give some item to one of $k$ agents, so that agent $j$ will get the item with probability $p_i$. Is there a cryptographic (or other) tool so that every agent (and even every observer) will be able to be convinced that the random drawing was indeed fair?

Comment: Are the agents allowed to know $p_0$..$p_k$?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=4232861

Answer (score 19):

If I am understanding the problem correctly, it would seem to amount to public flipping a $k$-sided coin. There seem to be lots of ways to do this if you assume bit commitment. One example would be having each party generate a random integer between 0 and $k-1$, using bit commitment to publicly commit to that bit string. Then once each agent has committed, they all publicly reveal their secret integer. The winning agent is then the one indexed by the sum of the integers modulo $k$. If even one agent is honest, then the flip must be random.

Of course one problem with this is that it requires bit commitment. Information theoretic schemes for bit commitment are impossible for both classical and quantum computing (though Adrian Kent recently proposed a scheme exploiting relativity). However, secure bit commitment can be achieved with computational assumptions.

Comment: My problem with this approach is that if you want to convince a lot of outside observers from fairness, then each of them has to commit a bit and you must be sure that each of them will reveal the proof of their commitment.  You can't just ignore the bit of an observer that does not reveal their proof because then the last observer to reveal could manipulate the lottery result by deciding whether or not to reveal his proof.

Comment: @user8067: I don't believe it is possible without interaction or trusting that at least one party is honest. The reason I say this is that if the initial randomness is actually predetermined through a conspiracy of everyone participating at that point, then the entire process is deterministic and not random. However the problem requires the process be random, so this seems to be the best you can do.

Comment: (user8067 here) okay, but I'd still like a way where observers have to commit, but any observer can choose not to reveal their commit proof (or otherwise fail to follow the procedure) yet all other observers will be convinced the lottery is fair.

Comment: I'm not convinced that is possible.

Comment: As mentioned by Adam, the protocol suggested in this answer will be _insecure_ $\hspace{1.2 in}$ if the commitment scheme used is malleable. $\:$

Comment: @RickyDemer: There's not enough information in the question to tell what adversary model is applicable here. If Gil told us exactly what it's for, then it would be easier to prove whether or not a specific scheme meets his requirements. But that said, I have no doubt Gil is more than capable of checking whether or not our answers meet his needs.

Comment: Since the protocol given in your answer is not necessarily secure in the standard model, and Gil did not specify a different model, your answer should _say_ that your protocol is not necessarily secure in the standard model. $\:$ Even if Gil could check for errors in answers, the answers $\hspace{0.4 in}$ should be correct anyway so that other people can use them. $\;\;$

Comment: @RickyDemer: It's not at all clear to me what the obvious model is for this case. It strongly depends the setup, and it's not obvious what the default assumptions should be. It's a little much to downvote and start acting like both my answer and Lev's are wrong. They don't explicitly include the caveat pointed out in Adam's answer. Note that I am -not- editing my answer, because without more information from Gil, I don't see it making sense to guess about the adversary model, and so I am leaving it as general as possible (not specifying whether or not the bit commitment need be non-maliable).

Comment: @JoeFitzsimons: Ah, I see your point about there being no obvious model here. I suppose what I should have said was that can only come up with contrived models (such as a trusted party that can inspect alleged states) to make not-necessarily non-malleable commitment useful for this problem. It's a bit little to not mention malleability, since Gil could have accepted this answer without providing more information.

Comment: @RickyDemer: Well, secure communications channels seemed to me like a reasonable thing to assume, but maybe not. It really depends on what Gil wants this for.

Answer (score 15):

As other users have hinted at, this is a well-studied problem in cryptography. It is called "coin-flipping" and is a special case of multiparty computation.

What protocol does the job actually depends on the context quite a lot.

- In the "standalone" setting, the protocol will be run in isolation, without players being involved in other protocols (or indeed, any interaction with the outside world) at the same time. There is a wonderfully thorough treatment of this in Oded Goldreich's textbook "Foundations of Cryptography" (Volume 2, I think).

Just to give an idea of how subtle it is, the "everybody commits to random values" protocol suggested by another responder is *insecure* if the commitment scheme you use is malleable. Nonmalleable commitment schemes do give you a secure protocol, but they are a bit complicated to design.

- In settings where participants are involved in other concurrent protocols, you want a protocol that is *composable*. There are various notions of composability, but the strongest one, called *universal composability*, requires some additional set-up assumptions (for example, a PKI or a common random string visible to all parties but controllable by none of them). I don't know of an accessible treatment of this topic, unfortunately. But looking at a recent paper on either universal composability or nonmalleable commitment would be a good place to start.

Comment: “a common random string visible to all parties but controllable by none of them” is exactly what we want to generate.

Comment: and after somehow solving that problem once, one can universally composably $\hspace{1 in}$ solve it again (arbitrarily many times). $\:$

Comment: I think UC commitment is known for Registered Public Key setup (which is a stronger assumption than PKI) and multi-string setup (which is a weaker assumption than common random string).

Comment: Welcome to the site, Adam!

Answer (score 11):

**Note: please read the comments below.  This protocol seems to have problems.**

---

I don't know much crypto, but perhaps the following would work. Assuming the $p_j$'s are publicly known, all that's needed to determine the winner is to select a random number from [0,1].

Here's the process:
Each agent selects a random vector in $\{0,1\}^b$, where $b$ is the number of bits of precision that are needed for the process.  Then they all cryptography commit to their vectors using known protocols.  Finally, once all the vectors are committed to, all their vectors are revealed (and checked) and XORed and the result is the random number to be used.  Namely the resulting vector is the binary representation of digits past the decimal point.

Any agent can be sure the chosen random number came uniformly at random by choosing his own vector uniformly at random.  For any observer to be convinced, they have to trust that at least one agent followed the protocol, but if none did, I guess nobody really wanted a fair lottery to begin with.

Comment: Sorry Lev, I've just noticed your answer. When I started writing an answer there was nothing here, but we both seem to have come up with very similar answers.

Comment: No worries! Seems we're on the right track, then.

Comment: Yes, actually I think there are a lot of papers on this in the context of coin flipping, but I don't really know that literature well enough to give a proper answer based on it.

Comment: The earliest reference I know is: M. Blum. Coin Flipping By Telephone. CRYPTO 1981: 11-15. Can be downloaded at http://dm.ing.unibs.it/giuzzi/corsi/Support/papers-cryptography/Coin_flipping.pdf

Comment: As mentioned by Adam, the protocol suggested in this answer will be _insecure_ $\hspace{1.2 in}$ if the commitment scheme used is malleable. $\:$

Comment: That makes sense. However, I don't think Gil's question asked about adversaries attacking the lottery, etc.

Comment: What else might Gil's question be about? $\:$

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped.  Of course if everyone were honest there'd be no question.  But what types of attacks a system should prevent is unclear to me.  Also, I don't really see a problem -- why not just use a non-malleable commitment scheme?

Comment: The problem is that your answer does not *say* to use a non-malleable commitment scheme. $\hspace{.3 in}$ In fact, "the standard" commitment scheme is malleable in a way that would make an implementation of your answer with it trivially insecure. $\:$

Comment: Thinking about it again, I don't see why.  If everyone first commits to their vectors, anyone honest can make sure his vector wasn't tampered with.  Then, when the vectors are revealed abd XORed, it's too late to tamper.  Where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Everyone could make sure that their vector wasn't tampered with by just sending their vector (which obviously wouldn't work either). $\:$ What's also needed is that the other vectors to be $\hspace{.4 in}$ used are (computationally) independent of one's own vector. $\;\;$

Comment: There's a standard attack, if you use standard bit commitment schemes (e.g., hashing).  Let's consider the case with two parties, Alice and Bob, where Alice goes first.  After Alice broadcasts her commitment, Bob can copy it.  After Alice opens her commitment, Bob can open his the same now.  Now their random vectors are equal, so they xor to zero -- Bob was able to force the final value to zero, a contradiction of the requirement for fairness.

Comment: @D.W. Thanks for the clear explanation -- that makes sense.

Answer (score -3):

Passive observers can't verify that the drawing wasn't staged. Inputs into pseudorandom process can be chosen to give desired result.

However if the observer can supply a random number that he knows is random AND make sure that other agents won't change their inputs afterwards (because they could compensate his effect with their inputs), then he can be sure that the result was indeed random.

This requires *commitment scheme* which we don't know any that is mathematically proven to be secure but in practice can be realized using secure hash (such as SHA3).

Consider this example:

[image]

I've made an example implementation. You can see it live here: https://mrogalski.eu/cl/ or check sources on [GitHub](https://github.com/mafik/crypto-lottery).

Comment: This is already noted in Joe's answer.

Comment: The graphic illustration is very nice!

Comment: The graphics are very pretty but your answer contains nothing that isn't in the existing answers.